# set data type when exporting to excel

Tags: grails, export, export-to-excel

I'm using Grails 1.3.4 with the export 0.9.5 plug in.

I have a formatter that I use that sets the date format to 'YYYY-MM-DD' when exporting to excel.  But this doesn't change the data type.  The date is exported to Excel as a string/general data type.

```
def dateFormat = { domain, value ->
    if(value instanceof Date){
         return new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd").format(value)
    }
    return value
}

Map formatters = [ecd:dateFormat, completed:dateFormat, dateCreated:dateFormat, approvedDate:dateFormat, dpaECD:dateFormat]
exportService.export(params.format, response.outputStream,exportList, jobService.parseColNames(columns), labels, formatters, null)
```

Is there a way to export data and set the datatype of a column in excel so the user doesn't have to manually set the cell/column formatting to 'Date' every time after exporting?

Comment: Clearly seen the closure `dateFormat` accepts two parameters, where is the closure called with those parameters?

Comment: i'd assume they are called in the export service?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you want to use that plugin? It didn't work so well to me.

I've been using the JXL plugin for Grails for a while and it works perfectly.

It even has an option to write the Excel file to the response, so that the user can directly download the file using my REST service.

The link is: http://grails.org/plugin/jxl

Here is an example of how simple it is to create workbooks:

```
new ExcelBuilder().workbook('/path/to/test.xls') {
    sheet('SheetName') {
        cell(0,0,'Current Date')
        cell(0,1,new Date())
    }
}
```

Note that the `cell()` method has 3 parameters: column, row and value. This third parameter can be a number, string or date, and it formats it perfectly.

You can find more information [here](https://github.com/sjurgemeyer/grails-jxl-plugin/wiki/Tutorial).